# jQuery Globalize - must build?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I am looking through the documentation and features for jQuery Globalize (https://github.com/jquery/globalize) and although it is a bit heavy and complex, it seems to do most of what I want.

The problem is maintenance.

As I understand it, to have access to each of the modules (messages, numbers, etc), I must first run the build in order to acquire a `./dist` folder. So in my company's automated build system (largely ant-driven), the following steps would be required:

1. Ensure Node installed
2. Ensure Grunt and Bower installed
3. Run both `npm install` and `bower install`
4. Modify the grunt task to exclude the failing "commit" task (why do they even want an automatic commit on build?)
5. Run the whole grunt to get a `./dist` folder
6. Execute my project grunt file, which copies the files out of this dist and further processes them

This is rather heavy when all we really need are the files ultimately found in `dist`. The bigger problem is that an update of the plugin then requires downloading the repo again and running through the same process and hope that dependency fetching and grunt build execution tasks don't fail.

Does anyone familiar with globalize know a better way to do this that's more future-proof? Any idea why the `dist` files arent' just part of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned directly in the README.md file, you need to go to a "tagged branch". This means going to the "releases" tab of the repository and picking an appropriate release. This will download a versioned release which includes the `dist` folder.

Clicking the "download" button in the sidebar will only retrieve the master development branch, which is not tagged and does not include `dist`.

As of this writing, the tagged branches found on the "releases" tab are at this link: https://github.com/jquery/globalize/releases